# image classification using linear SVC

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am trying to learn how the linear SVC works in SVM, and for such trying to replicate a simple experiment by training and testing with different parameters. The problem is that i can't seem to understand how exactly do i use my data to train and test the linear SVC algorithm. Basically, what i want to do is use image recognition with Linear SVC.

I have 5 frames from 5 different people, with 22 features for each image. My goal is to simply obtain training rates for the images, my problem is that i am obtaining 100% rates, when i was expecting something around 80% more or less, i wonder how could i achieve proper recognition rates, then?

```
import sklearn
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics

dataset = np.asarray(data)
target = np.asarray([1]*5 + [2]*5 + [3]*5 + [4]*5 + [5]*5)
svc_1 = SVC(kernel='linear')




X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
        dataset, target, test_size=0.35, random_state=0)


def train_and_evaluate(clf, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):
    
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print ("Accuracy on training set:")
    print (clf.score(X_train, y_train))
    print ("Accuracy on testing set:")
    print (clf.score(X_test, y_test))
    
    y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
    
    print ("Classification Report:")
    print (metrics.classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
    print ("Confusion Matrix:")
    print (metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))


train_and_evaluate(svc_1, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)
```

This is my code, and for saving visualization, i uploaded my 25x22 matrix to pastebin: https://pastebin.com/6hL6Dign

This is my output:

```
Accuracy on training set:
1.0
Accuracy on testing set:
1.0
Classification Report:
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           1       1.00      1.00      1.00         1
           2       1.00      1.00      1.00         1
           3       1.00      1.00      1.00         1
           4       1.00      1.00      1.00         3
           5       1.00      1.00      1.00         3

    accuracy                           1.00         9
   macro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00         9
weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00         9
```

In short, what i want to do is have lower rates as i decrease the number of rows or/and number of columns in my dataset, but i keep getting 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is - your data set is really separated well between the 5 classes.

**Clue #1 - target shuffling**

Shuffling the target caused the accuracy to drop. Try adding after the target definition:

```
random.shuffle(target)  # Requires `import shuffle`
```

**Clue #2 - PCA**

I used [principal component analysis (PCA)](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) to visualize your data by reducing to two features:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca_res = pca.fit_transform(data)
plt.scatter(pca_res[:, 0], pca_res[:, 1], color=list(map(' rgbyc'.__getitem__, target)))
```

Result:

[image: PCA visualization]

It seems quite clear that the classes are separated well - the in-group variance is much small the the between-group variance. Apparently the SVC has no trouble detecting the correct classes of the test set even with this small sample size.

**Edit**

It appears that PCA wasn't even necessary. A single feature (e.g. the second one) yields 100% separation. Try you code with:

```
dataset = np.asarray(data)[:, 1:2]
```

And with visualization:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.boxplot(x=target, y=dataset[:, 1])  # Original dataset used here
```

Result:

[image]